# How to get last word of an HTML element

Tags: java, html

I have an Element :

```
 <p align="center"><font class="bodytext"><strong><u>Address</u></strong><br /> 123 Upper East , text text2 s (s)465561 </font></p>
```

or it could be a little bit different in this format:

```
 <p align="center"><font class="bodytext"><strong><u>Address</u></strong><br /> 123 Upper East , text text2 s 465561 </font></p>
```

And what I need is the last number (only the number:

```
465561
```

What is the best way to do that ? I'm thinking of using some element extraction or regexp, but couldn't figure out.

```
getElementsByTag("font");
```

and

```
Pattern titleFinder = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher regexMatcher = titleFinder.matcher(subjectString);
```

do not really work for me.

Comment: do not use regex for html

Comment: There is anchor tag in your regex pattern, whereas in examples there's no such tag. Why is this? Can't you just get the text of the correct HTML node as `String` (I suppose that this is `subjectString`) and find the second group of digits: `"(\d+)"`?

Comment: Quite simple to do it in Python with BeautifulSoup. Is that an option?

Comment: Strip all the tags. Trims all the spaces and split them based on " " =(space  character) and select the last element.

Comment: For some reasons I dont use python here, I think jsoup is something similar to beautifulsoup, there should be a way here

Comment: How do you get that element(what library you use)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is brute force expression but it works as expected and is really easy to understand
and you don't care about tags, another numbers in your string as long as differ from 6 digit together pattern

```
 //Get any last 6 digits
    String pattern = "(.*)([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(.*)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String updated = "<p align=\"center\"><font class=\"bodytext\"><strong><u>Address</u></strong><br /> 123 Upper East , text text2 s (s)465561 </font></p>";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(updated);
    if(m.matches()){
        System.out.println(m.group(2)+m.group(3)+m.group(4)+m.group(5)+m.group(6)+m.group(7));

    }
```

Got:

```
465561

Process finished with exit code 0
```

m.group(1) and last m.group(7) are the leftovers :)

Comment: sadly I cant get my element to string like above

Comment: Yes, I think it is smart solution for this case! The 6-digit-unit should be unique! I get it done after convert my element to string by: elements.toString(). Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

grab the item, e.g. by **getElementsByTagName("font")**; (you will get an array)
assume the content of getElementsByTagName("font")[0] is " 123 Upper East , text text2 s 465561 ";

```
var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName("font")[0].innerText.split(" ");
```

// will result in array
    ["Address 123", "Upper", "East", ",", "text", "text2", "s", "(s)465561"]

```
var resultnum = tmp[tmp.length-1];  
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Number is " +resultnum;

//resultnum = resultnum.replace(/(s)/);`
```

// replace possible (s) (not quite sure about regex)

Comment: getElementsByTag("font") will still return element, it not yet an array, I just tried

Comment: But I dont have this method in my java, only getElementsByTag dont have: getElementsByTagName

Comment: ok, so try getElementsByTag, but according to Mozilla Developers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName it's called "TagName". There you can see it returns an array.

Comment: in the code above I print the resultnum to a seperate <p id="result"></p>

Comment: do you mean String[]  instead of var ?

Comment: let me get this clear, do you want to alter this html-stuff with Java or JavaScript?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30930/discussion-between-dsuess-and-user1314404)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
Pattern titleFinder = Pattern.compile(".*\\D+(\\d+)\\D*", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: It was an element (so I edited my post), if there is no simple way to convert element to string, may be I should avoid it

Answer (score 0):

```
TransformerFactory transFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transFactory.newTransformer();
StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(element), new StreamResult(buffer));
String input = buffer.toString();
String fontText = input.substring(input.indexOf("<font>") + 2 + "font".length(), input.indexOf("</font>"));
String textPieces[] = fontText.split(" ");
// textPieces[textPieces.length - 1] will have the last word
```

Comment: It was an element (so I edited my post), if there is no simple way to convert element to string, may be I should avoid it

Comment: 'transformer.transform(new DOMSource(element), new StreamResult(buffer));'
that line get "no suitable constructor for DOMSource(element) error :(

Comment: What is the java datatype which holds your element? Not a node?